# Automapper Queryable Many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper, iqueryable

I am using AutoMapper 6.1.1 (latest stable) and I am fighting with mapping M:N relations. In the database schema as well in entities there is a left table L, the right table R and a association table A. The corresponding class A holds L.id, L, R.id and R - both ID's and navigation properties. The class L contains a collection of A. Everything with EF works well, there are no errors.

From the server I want to return some kind of LDto - it contains info from L and a collection of Rs. So what I want to do is extracting the R property from all of A instances and pass them to the result DTO.

Currently I am using this way:

```
 config.CreateMap<L, LDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Rs,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.As.Select(a => a.R)));
```

Somewhere in the service logic there is something like:

```
 lData.Where(l => l.code == "Code").Include(l => l.As.Select(....)).ProjectTo<LDto>;
```

If there are data everywhere and `Include`s for defined mapping it works fine. However there is no guarantee there exists any association instance A or not in all of cases I want to load the nested structures and having null in the response is fine for these purposes.

In this case (or I believe it is because of missing data) I get this error:

```
 Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: source
```

I've tried this (simplified):

```
 var queryable = getData(); //OK
 var list = queryable.ToList(); //OK
 var result = list.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<LDto>() --error mentioned above
```

How can I handle setting the automapper to extract collection of objects from other collection when there is no guarantee the source collection is not null?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `ProjectTo` should be used on *real* EF queryable, in which case `Include`s are irrelevant (ignored) and collections/references are never null (since the whole thing is translated to SQL). `ToList().AsQueryable().ProjectTo()` makes no sense, if you work with enumerables, then use `Mapper.Map` instead.

Comment: `var result = queryable.ProjectTo<LDto>();`

Comment: @IvanStoev: you are right - I did this construction just to force the EF to materialize results and ensure there is not any other issue in EF.